# If I replace Windows with Ubuntu, will I still have to back up my stuff?

Tags: system-installation, backup

I've heard from people that to get both Windows and Ubuntu you have to make a backup.  Now, since I don't want to have to pay money for an external hard drive (and spend a few quadrillion years getting stuff on there), can you replace Windows without having to use a backup?

Comment: You should have a backup. Ever. Even if do not switch operating system. Hard disks will fail. The only situation where you do not need a backup is if you do not value your personal data anything.

Comment: Yes, if you choose the right options, you won't need to back up your data to still have it after installing. But just the fact that you have a computer means you really, really, really, REALLY SHOULD have a backup, whether or not you are installing Ubuntu or not. Take it from someone who has personally lost data and not had a backup, you don't fully realize how much you need a backup until you end up losing data and not having one. Please, learn from others (mine included) mistakes, instead of having to go through the pain of lost data yourself.

Comment: I just reread the title, I should warn you that THE REPLACE OPTION WILL ERASE your data -- I believe that it is the install alongside option that tries to keep it.